# How to actually set utf-8 encoding in SQLAlchemy / Postgres in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a web application using Flask and a Postgresql database (using SQLAlchemy). It works just fine. Except for a little problem: all text data comes in some encoding that it's not utf-8 (at least I think it's not).

I looked around to see any possible solutions and this is what I've tried:

- Include this line at every Python file in the project:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

- Set the engine like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
        self.engine = sql.create_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'], encoding='utf8')
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()
        self.metadata = sql.MetaData()
```

And a few variations of these previous items like `client_encoding='utf8` instead of `encoding='utf8`. I also tried these solutions:

- [Encoding error with sqlalchemy and postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783505/encoding-error-with-sqlalchemy-and-postgresql)
- [SQLAlchemy result for UTF-8 column is of type 'str', why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819192/sqlalchemy-result-for-utf-8-column-is-of-type-str-why)
- [how to use `charset` and `encoding` in `create_engine` of SQLAlchemy (to create pandas dataframe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279863/how-to-use-charset-and-encoding-in-create-engine-of-sqlalchemy-to-create)
- [python encoding utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092437/python-encoding-utf-8)
- [Python encoding unicode utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535360/python-encoding-unicode-utf-8)

For example, this is one of my select functions (but the problem happens in every select / insert / update functions):

```py
def get_produtos(self, id):
        produtos = sql.Table('produtos', self.metadata, autoload=True,
                             autoload_with=self.engine).columns
        parceiros = sql.Table('parceiros', self.metadata, autoload=True,
                              autoload_with=self.engine).columns
        q = sql.select([produtos.id, produtos.nome, parceiros.nome_parceiro,
                        produtos.valor, produtos.qtd_desconto,
                        parceiros.id_parceiro])
        q = q.where(produtos.id == id)
        return self.conn.execute(q).fetchall()
```

The program does not raises any exception but the data just comes with the wrong encoding.

This is how the data is in my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvRTN.png

This is how the data shows up in my app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCj0C.png

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the output of this command from the psql console: `\l <name of your database` (or `psql --list | grep '<name of your database>'`.  This will show us the defaults for your database.

Comment: The application is running on Heroku so I can only acces the database itself. Running the command you said logged in my database (not sure if it's the right thing to do), I got this: https://i.imgur.com/S1ZQxOT.png

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. You are right suspecting that _all text data comes in some encoding that it's not utf-8_. `'Se‡Æo Eletr“nicos'` is definitely a result from this: `'Seção Eletrônicos'.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252')`…

Comment: @JosefZ this problem was actually solved a while ago, but thanks for answering since it might help other people

Comment: @MarcosSombra Well. Then, you should [answer the question yoursef](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and finally accept the answer  ([See this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JosefZ said, it's a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.
This problem in particular occured because some entries were inserted via shell and there was no encoding and led to this inconsistency.